# how to use generate for multiple module instantiation in verilog

Tags: verilog

Please tell me the error. I'm using the following code and each time I get this error during compilation for the "generate"
 wordsize has already been defined

```
genvar k;
generate
  always@(posedge clk)
  begin
    for (k=1; k<`wordsize-1; k=k+1)
      begin
        I2S_dff instance (.d(sd), .q(q_out[i]), .r(wsp), .en(dec_out[i]), .sck(clk));
        datareg_in = |q_out;
      end
  end
endgenerate
```

Comment: Module instantiations do not go inside `always` blocks.

Comment: Also, if your genvar is `k`, that's what you need to use to index the bits, not `i`.

Comment: @DaveTweed yeah I realized about the genvar after rechecking the pice, that was just a typographical mistake. But even after correcting it the error was there. I'm going to try removing the always block and hope it works !!

Answer (score 1):

```
genvar k;
generate for (k = 1; k <`wordsize - 1; k = k + 1) begin
    I2S_dff instance (.d(sd), .q(q_out[i]), .r(wsp), .en(dec_out[i]), .sck(clk));
    datareg_in = |q_out;

 end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the always block, but keep everything inside of it. The wordsize error is odd, though.  That should be taken care of in the preprocessor before the generate statement is evaluated.

Comment: will do the same and see if it works !!